# How was the Fubini theorem used to calculate this integral?

Tags: integration

[image]

I am confused about how the Fubini theorem is used in the integral in the red box because the Fubini theorem is supposed to work with double integrals but this is a single integral.

Comment: Please don't delete a question promptly after receiving an answer. That is rude to the nice people trying to help you by answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an integral inside the expression of $\pi(\beta|\eta_1, \eta_2)$ of which its limit is from $1$ to $\infty$, hence it is actually a double integral.

The question is of the form of

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_1^\infty G(\beta_k, t_k) \,\, dt_k d\beta_k $$ which becomes $$ \int_1^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty  G(\beta_k, t_k) \,\,  d\beta_kdt_k$$

after Fubini's theorem.